# how to write a query for following scenario in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables as follows..

**Drug_Master**

```
PKDrugId - int

DrugName - varchar

DrugType - varchar
```

**Stock_Master**

```
PKStockId - int

FKDrugId - int

Total_quantity_on_hand - int
```

I want to write a query which shows `DrugName` instead of `FKDrugId` in `Stock_Master` Table.

can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JOIN` the tables like so:

```
SELECT
  s.PKStockId,
  d.DrugName,
  s.Total_quantity_on_hand 
FROM Stock_Master s
INNER JOIN Drug_Master d ON s.FKDrugId  = d.PKDrugId;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cf1b0/1).

Please read more about `JOIN`s:

- [**Join (SQL)<sup>From Wikipedia</sup>**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29).
- [**Visual Representation of SQL Joins**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins).
- [**Another Visual Explanation of SQL Joins**](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

You might need to `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` to get the unmatched rows. For instance, if you need to include those drug names that has no stocks entries in the other `Stock_Master` table you can do this:

```
SELECT
  ISNULL(s.PKStockId, 0),
  d.DrugName,
  ISNULL(s.Total_quantity_on_hand, 0) 
FROM Drug_Master d
LEFT JOIN Stock_Master s ON s.FKDrugId  = d.PKDrugId;
```

[**LEFT JOIN SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cf1b0/4)

You can use a correlated subquery instead of `JOIN` like so:

```
SELECT 
  s.PKStockId,
  (SELECT d.DrugName
   FROM  Drug_Master d 
   WHERE s.FKDrugId  = d.PKDrugId) AS DrugName,
  s.Total_quantity_on_hand 
FROM Stock_Master s;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo using a subquery**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cf1b0/5)

But it is better to use `JOIN`.